# Xcode 11.3.1 compatibility

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, version

I am building an IOS app on XCode 11.3.1 using Swift and would like to know which Iphone models will be compatible with the app. The simulator shows Iphone 8 and above. Does it mean that lower Iphones will not be able to run it?

I can't find a good explanation or a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Xcode version is not the key to supporting older iPhones and their OSes.

Instead, look out for your deployment target. The lower you choose, the more ‘old’ iPhones you get. For example, if you choose iOS 8 as your deployment target, your app will support older devices that can use iOS 8 but not 13.

The simulator only shows a list of devices that supports the newest iOS version supported by the current version of Xcode, but may not necessarily mean that it is limited to those.

Do note that newer APIs be used for the older devices, though you could still make it such that it will work for newer devices, with a fallback to some older APIs just for the older devices.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it makes a lot of sense.